# How to solve for getting average of them

Tags: arithmetic, puzzle

I am trying to solve this problem

```
If x+y= 6, y+z= 7 , and x+z= 9 , what is the average of x , y and z ?
```

Well how i am trying to do is getting the value of 'X' , 'Y' and 'Z' which are `X = 4 , Y = 2 , Z = 5` then i take their average as `4+2+5` then 11/3 , but i this is not giving me the right answer. Any help appriciated

Comment: It is the right answer. It may not be the expected format? Another way, without explicitly determining $x,y,z$ is $$(x+y) + (y+z) + (x+z) = 2x+2y+2z = 6+7+9 = 22,$$ and so the average is $\frac{22}{6} = \frac{11}{3}$.

Comment: But they are showing the write answer as '113'

Comment: That evidently should be $11/3$; whether the omission of the division operator $/$ was intentional or not, I can but guess.

Comment: Off-topic comment, but I just had to say that I really like your user-name, @Wish_2_fly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align} \underbrace{(x+y)}_{=\,6} + \underbrace{(y+z)}_{=\,7} + \underbrace{(x + z)}_{=\,9} & = 2x + 2y + 2z \\ &= 2(x + y + z) = 6+7+9 \\ &\iff x + y + z =\frac 12(6+7+9)=11\end{align}$$

To compute the average, now, calculate $\dfrac{x + y+z}{3} = \dfrac {11}3$.